# How can I create super classes in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

For example in my collection classes I call a method called test to artificially populate my collections.

I want this method to be accessible to all my collections.

I'm sure there are multiple ways to do this but which way is de-facto?

FYI, the this is the method:

```
    test: function () {
        var models = [],
            Model = this.model;
        _.times(8, function (n) {
            models.push(new Model({id: (n + 1)}));
        });
        this.set(models);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({...});
var FooCollection = Collection.extend({...});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to define a class that extends `Backbone.Collection` and then extend that new class everytime you create one of your own collections.  I would also wrap it in your own domain so that you can get easy access to it with dot syntax, and you can add more custom classes, like `Backbone.Model` extensions.

```
var MyStuff = (function() {
  function MyStuff() {};

  MyStuff.MyFancyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    test: function....
  });

  return MyStuff;

})();
```

So when you want to use this collection later you will use something like this:

```
var MySpecificCollection = MyStuff.MyFancyCollection.extend({...});
```

Comment: haha, whoops, mixed in some coffeescript!....let me revise that  So used to using coffeescript these days!  (It is pretty nice)